# Makefile builds using multiple compilers but only one specified

Tags: c++, makefile, clang, llvm

In my makefile I specify as follows:

```
CXX ?= /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/bin/clang++
LINK ?= /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/bin/clang++

...

all: /Users/zeno/polynomialOpticsNuke/src/polynomialOpticsBlur.dylib

.PRECIOUS : %.os
%.os: %.cpp
    $(CXX) --version $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGSPOLYNOMIALOPTICS) ${OPTFLAGSPOLYNOMIALOPTICS} -o $(@) $<
%.dylib: %.os
    $(LINK) --version $(LDFLAGSPOLYNOMIALOPTICS) $(LINKFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(FRAMEWORKS) -o $(@) $<
%.a: %.cpp
    $(CXX) --version $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGSPOLYNOMIALOPTICS) ${OPTFLAGSPOLYNOMIALOPTICS} -o lib$(@) $<
```

When running this, I get multiple compiler versions.. (I stripped irrelevant output)

```
c++ --version /Users/zeno/polynomialOpticsNuke/src/polynomialOpticsBlur.os /Users/zeno/polynomialOpticsNuke/src/polynomialOpticsBlur.cpp
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/bin/clang++ --version /Users/zeno/polynomialOpticsNuke/src/polynomialOpticsBlur.dylib /Users/zeno/polynomialOpticsNuke/src/polynomialOpticsBlur.os
clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/bin
```

How is it possible that the compiler uses apple clang (3.9) and the linker clang (5.0)? I have set them both to the same path..

I also have these environment variables:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I got it to work by swapping the CXX variable for the path in the build commands. Why didn't the variable work? Strange.

Comment: What happens if you change `?=` to `:=` in the makefile?  Is it possible that `CXX` and/or `LINK` is already defined in your environment?

Comment: `?=` means "define this if not already defined". Use `=` or `:=`.

Comment: You can use an `$(info CXX=${CXX}  LINK=${LINK})` on the third line to debug.  I suspect that @G.M. is correct in that one of these is already defined in your environment before the makefile is parsed.